# Undergraduate research paper

Tags: publications, career-path, research-undergraduate

Is it possible to publish a research paper in economics at the under graduation level without studying it? I am doing BSc in physics math and statistics at Bangalore University. However I have independently studied economics and started doing research. How do I publish a paper? Please guide me.

Answer (score 4):

Do you have a sufficient background in Economics to publish a high level research paper? I would say share your paper with a researcher/professor in Economics near you, and see if he/she thinks its a good idea to publish, from there, you can ask his experience and ask him to go forward. You need to connect with a local professor though, so I would say email one, and share your ideas (or find one at the university you're attending)

Comment: What is econ ??

Comment: @TejasSuresh Economics

Comment: Sir my only doubt is .Since i study in a not so good college .does that affect my chances of publishing in a good journal and secondly i dont have economics in my course so will that affect also ??

Comment: @TejasSuresh  No it doesn't. You seem like a smart individual, and you should talk to your professors. Its a good idea to have taken economics, but if you feel like you have sufficient reading, then it may be worth a try. I would also recommend submitting to an undergraduate research journal: http://www.cur.org/resources/students/undergraduate_journals/

Comment: Can u suggest me some journals amongst this that would be suitable for me??Can i have ur email id Sir ??

Comment: What benefits do i get by publishing in journals at a young age???

Comment: You could have a better chance of getting into graduate school. If you want to become a researcher, that will obviously be essential.

Comment: Sir ,can i publish a paper on my own as i am quite confident about its contents

Comment: What journal would you use? Seeing that you are quite confident, then why not try to submit it in an undergraduate journal like the link I suggested. If it is indeed good, then it will be recognized. What is your topic? - if I may ask.

Comment: The topic is concerning privatisation of public sector units in india ,its socio political impact ,its economic consequences .

Comment: Hmm...Interesting. I highly recommend that you reach out to some professor through email and send him your paper

Comment: Sure will do it .

Comment: Can u give me three reputed journals which can publish my work ??